# Is there a way to extract URI or URL in View Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to extract URI or URL from a text that's in view? I basically have a print out of content from DB which looks like so;

```
<%= saved.content %>
```

and that sometimes has a URL in it, most of the time. I know that `URI.extract` will take anything from so, so in controller;

```
URI.extract('some text with some type of http://www.com')
```

but how would you do the same if you wanted to extract the url from a content that's printed in a view?

Suggestions.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to transform them into real clickable URLs? If so, [`autolink`](https://github.com/tenderlove/rails_autolink) or [`auto_html`](https://github.com/dejan/auto_html) are probably some good options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods available to the controller are also available in the view

```
<%= URI.extract(saved.content) %>
```

Comment: beautiful, yes... some how I thought I needed `{}` some where in there lol but it works perfect. -Thank you @JTG

Answer (score 0):

If it is already printed to the view/loaded in the DOM, couldn't you grab/use it via JS/jQuery? Something like:

`$('#the_id_of_the_thing').value()`